# How INS_IsProcedureCall() works?

Tags: intel-pin

In [Pin Documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#ge3a360d2e7f237a7a5d3d6bc63611f39) for `INS_IsProcedureCall(INS ins)`, it is given that

> true if ins is a procedure call. This filters out call instructions that are (ab)used for other purposes

On the other hand, there is `INS_IsCall(INS ins)` which will return `true` for all the `call` instructions.

My question is, how exactly both these functions differ? More precisely, what kind of call instructions will be returned `true` by `INS_IsCall(INS ins)` but not by `INS_IsProcedureCall(INS ins)`?

Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A call could be a real procedure call (using INS_IsProcedureCall) or an instruction pointer materialization (using [INS_IsPcMaterialization](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__IA32.html#gd9a598eb4f51a148ec541f3df80da890)).

Basically only those calls that are not true by INS_IsPcMaterialization function will be true by INS_IsProcedureCall.